# Django SerializerModel does not return the fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I create an Django REST API with Serializer but  if i test the serializer I receive just an empty result.

Actually I should receive an

```
>>> from heating.serializers import RoomSerializer
>>> s = RoomSerializer()
>>> print(repr(s))
RoomSerializer():
... LIST OF FIELDS WITH SOME ADDITIONAL INFOMRATION...
>>>
```

**Model**

```
class Room(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
```

**Serializer**

```
class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description')
```

**Shell output**

```
>>> from heating.serializers import RoomSerializer
>>> s = RoomSerializer()
>>> print(repr(s))
RoomSerializer():
>>>
```

I strongly belive, that there is a mistake in my code, but I have no clue where?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any information to the serializer, why should it return data when none are provided ?

Please take some time to go through the [tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/)

Comment: Thank you die YouTube reply. I read this Tutorial an die it. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#using-modelserializers at the third section: I should replace the Code. And in comparison to my code it is the same. So i don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my bad. I misread and understood this was about missing values for the fields. I took your code sample here and it gave me the expected representation with the fields. as you can see at https://gist.github.com/xordoquy/0453714a8c28afbcc62da05d705cd56f

Comment: ok.. now it works. But I have totaly no idea what was wrong.  I just restart the `python manage.py shell`. Thank you for clarification, that my concept was correct.